# Memory efficiency .txt appending Python

Tags: python, csv, memory-management, append

I have created a list of .txt file directories in Python and then wrote a function to combine these.

```
def combine_directory_txt(FilePaths):
    """
    This function will combine all files in a directory by importing each,
    and appending them to a single output. It only works for csv's (.txt) with
    a delimeter of "|"
    """
    Output = pd.DataFrame() # Dataframe which will store the final table
    Increment = 0
    Total = len(FilePaths)

    # Import each file and join them together
    for file in FilePaths:
        Increment += 1
        Import = pd.read_csv(file, sep = '|', error_bad_lines = False,
                                   low_memory = False, encoding='mbcs' )
        Output = Output.append(Import)
        print (Increment, " of ", Total, " joined")
        del Import
    return Output
```

This works fine, except my PC is struggling with MemoryErrors. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I realise I've used "low_memory = false", this process is to be repeated monthly so I cannot know what the columns will look like and my code was failing very early due to all the dtype warnings. Is this the correct approach? Should I have written code to work out what the dtypes are then assign them to cut down on memory?

Comment: Setting the dtypes explicitly can help, especially if you know the range of some of the attributes. However, if you really have a lot of data and limited memory, eventually you will run into trouble. Instead I would suggest looking into whether it is necessary to have a single large dataframe. Can the code that use this dataframe work if it accesses the smaller dataframes one at a time, perhaps going through them multiple time? Does the code actually need all the data in the dataframes or can it work with a subset of their columns or information summarized from each dataframe?

Comment: Do all of your CSV files have the same format? i.e. same header/columns

Comment: @lightalchemist I am trying to output a single file to be processed elsewhere, so I am trying to make a single dataframe such that it can be exported.

Comment: @MartinEvans all of the files have the same format yes, but I don't know if they will be the same headers each time. However each time it is run all of the CSVs will have the same headers. I hope that is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is reading in every CSV file into memory and combining them all and returning the resulting dataframe. Instead you should process the CSV files one at a time, each time writing the results into an `output.csv` file.

The script below shows how this could be done. It adds the filename to use for the output. It assumes all files in the run share the same format, and that each have the same header. The header is written once to the output CSV file and then skipped over whilst reading.

```
import csv

def combine_directory_txt(file_paths, output_filename):
    # Get the header from the first CSV file passed
    with open(file_paths[0], "rb") as f_input:
        header = next(csv.reader(f_input, delimiter="|"))

    with open(output_filename, "wb") as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter="|")
        csv_output.writerow(header)     # Write the header once

        for file_name in file_paths:
            with open(file_name, "rb") as f_input:
                csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter="|")
                next(csv_input)     # Skip header
                csv_output.writerows(csv_input)

combine_directory_txt(["mbcs_1.txt", "mbcs_2.txt"], "output.csv")
```

Using this approach, the memory requirements will be greatly reduced.

Comment: When I tried to run this I got "TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function". I am also curious where this output csv will be saved? I am putting a location or just naming the file? I think this is due to a python 2 / 3 thing? I have two machines, one running 2 and one running 3. The code I showed before is for 3. But the machine I'd rather run it on is python 2.

Comment: You are using Python 2.x, I would recommend using Python 3.x as the encoding support is far better for processing CSV files. I have modified it for Python 2.x

Comment: This is for a work project, I have access to a Python 3 x machine, but most users are on 2.x and I am writing a script for somebody else. Sadly I can't force the move, I just have to best accommodate their needs

Answer (score 0):

### Note: Not tested. Use at own risk.

The main idea is to read data in chunks (number of rows) and append them to the file by passing the `chunksize` argument to `read_csv`. This argument can optionally be passed to `to_csv` for the same purpose. Although I have not profiled this code, in general, reading in chunks and writing in chunks can improve IO performance, especially for large files.

```
def combine_directory_txt(file_paths, output_filename, chunksize):
    """Merge collection of files.
    :param file_paths: Collection of paths of files to merge.
    :param output_filename: Path of output file (i.e., merged file).
    :param chunksize: Number of lines to read in at one time.    
    """
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as outfile:
        chunk_transfer(file_paths[0], outfile, chunksize, append=False)
        for path in file_paths[1:]:
            chunk_transfer(path, outfile, chunksize, append=True)

def chunck_transfer(path, outfile, chunksize, append, include_index=False):
    """Transfer file at path to outfile in chunks.
    :param path: Path of file to transfer.
    :param outfile: File handler for output file.
    :param chunksize: Number of lines to read at a time.
    :param append: Whether to append to file or write new file.
    :param include_index: Whether to include index of dataframe.
    """

    with open(path, "rb") as infile:
        df = pd.read_csv(infile, 
                         sep='|', 
                         error_bad_lines=False,
#                          low_memory=False,
                         encoding='mbcs',
                         chunksize=chunksize)

        if append:
            include_header = False
            mode = 'a'
        else:
            include_header = True
            mode = 'w'

        # Possible to pass chunksize as an argument to to_csv
        df.to_csv(outfile, mode=mode, header=include_header, index=include_index)
```